# How to get the Name and DeptId of the employees whose salary is greater than average of his department?

Tags: bigdata, apache-pig, hadoop2

I am newbie to Hadoop and pig.As per the question i able to drill down till the below script but how can i compare salary of person to his average salary of his dept. Following is the script written to get average salary of each department

```
A = LOAD 'Assignment_1_Input.log' USING PigStorage('\t') as (id:int,name:chararray,age:int,salary:int,deptid:int);
B = GROUP A by deptid;
STORE B INTO 'Assign1GrpByNew';
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group as grpId,AVG(A.salary) as grpAvgSal;
DUMP C;
```

Input File:

```
15878   mohan   24      8000    1
19173   ramya   27      10000   1
9527    krishna 35      40000   2
9528    raj     36      60000   2
16884   ravi    50      70000   2
```

Expected Output

```
ramya   1
raj 2
ravi    2
```

Help me out,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` A and C by deptid,grpId and `FILTER` where salary > grpAvgSal

```
A = LOAD 'Assignment_1_Input.log' USING PigStorage('\t') as (id:int,name:chararray,age:int,salary:int,deptid:int);
B = GROUP A by deptid;
STORE B INTO 'Assign1GrpByNew';
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group as grpId,AVG(A.salary) as grpAvgSal;

D = JOIN A BY deptid,C BY grpId;
E = FILTER D BY (A::salary > C::grpAvgSal);
DUMP E;
```

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY dept_id and compute the avg salary for each employee record and select those employees who salary is greater than avg.

**Snippet :**

```
inp_data = LOAD 'Assignment_1_Input.log' USING PigStorage('\t') as (id:int,name:chararray,age:int,salary:int,deptid:int);
inp_data_fmt = FOREACH(GROUP inp_data BY deptid) GENERATE FLATTEN(inp_data), AVG(inp_data.salary) AS avg_salary;
req_data = FILTER inp_data_fmt BY salary > avg_salary;
DUMP req_data;
```